# Return list of all files in a directory or just an item in list if path is a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering why this wouldn't work, Its suppose to return a `list` with one item which is the full path of a file. But if the user input path is a directory its suppose to return a `list` with all files in it.

The problem is it doesn't throw an error it just stops like its expecting another input. I have tried to debug but its hard to find because it keeps changing. I will comment all lines in english to to read what I assume/want the code to do

```
import re
import os, glob
# Program to extract emails from text files


def path_file():
    path = raw_input("Please enter path to file:\n> ") ## /home/gatsby/think/lead/ 
    if os.path.exists(path):
        print "Working" # doesn't print this infact it just freezes without an error message
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            print "test file"
            return glob.glob(path)
        else:
            print "test dir"
            print os.path.normpath(path) + os.sep ## for debugging
            return glob.glob(os.path.normpath(path) + os.sep + '*.*')
    #else:
        #raise SystemError
```

Comment: it works for me on python 2.7...I mean it prints 'Working' and 'test file' if the path exists and is a file...If it's not a file it ends the program which is normal looking at the code

Comment: Same for me with 2.7.3.. Try running with `python -v` or within `strace` to get some more details about where it's hanging up

Comment: It is not Python 3 code (I see `raw_input()` and `print` statements)